# Unable to prevent Hibernate from opening too many connections

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I'm using:  Hibernate 3.6.8 with mySQL, Tomcat 6, JDBC connection pooling

I've run into a problem where Hibernate is opening a large number of connections, which eventually causes my web app to not be able to get a new connection.
At first I thought the problem was that I was running without a connection pool, so I hooked up Tomcat JDBC pooling.

This made the problem worse.  Instead of failing after a handful of queries, it failed immediately.
This turned out to be because Hibernate was trying to open a larger number of connections than my pool size (30).
I checked, and everywhere I'm creating an EntityManager, I'm calling close(), within a finally clause if there's a try, so I wasn't sure why they were staying open.

Looking at the source for close(), I discovered that it doesn't actually close if there's a transaction open,
so I tried calling getTransaction().commit() on the entity manager, even though its just a select statment.  This had no effect.
Then I discovered this configuration flag, and turned it on:
`<property name="hibernate.ejb.discard_pc_on_close" value="true" />`

This made a difference, I got an exception when I tried to render the object for output:
failed to lazily initialize a collection of role : XXX.Comment.attachments, no session or session was closed

The issue seems to be that I make a number of queries to create a collection of Comments, and all of these queries keep a connection open.
The Comment class contains this:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinTable(name = "Object", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "parentId") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id") })
public List<Attachment> getAttachments()
{
    if (attachments == null)
    {
        attachments = new ArrayList<Attachment>();
    }
    return attachments;
}
```

I'll mention that there's some inheritance going on here.
Attachment is a subclass of KObject (table name Object in the db), and KObject contains the parentId used to map back to Comment (which is also a subclass of KObject).

For clarification, here's my call to the entity manager:

```
public <T> T findById(Class<T> objClass, String id)
{
    EntityManager em = theEMF.createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    try {
        T obj = em.find(objClass, id);
        return obj;
    } catch(NoResultException e) {
        return null;
    } finally {
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.clear();
        em.close();
    }   
}
```

theEMF is a static member variable that's initialized on first use.

I thought the solution would be making it @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER), but this had no effect.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How do you manage transactions in your application? Do you use any kind of dependency injection library/framework?

Comment: Do you use OpenSessionInViewFilter or something like that?

Comment: I use the EntityManager, which I understand is a wrapper around the session.  I've added code on that to the question.

Comment: I've also tried using "fetch all" in the HQL request, but that also seemed to have no effect.

Comment: Adding this configuration: <property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode" value="after_statement" /> solves the connection issue, but causes all writes to the database to throw this exception:  java.sql.SQLException: Can't call commit when autocommit=true

Comment: To fix the autocommit problem I need to add to the resource url: relaxAutoCommit=true. However, now there's a new problem where inserts don't work.  If I turn show_sql on, I see the inserts, but the database doesn't.  I tried adding an extra flush in, but no difference.

Comment: The after_statement release_mode is causing a rollback to happen after the insert, but before the commit.  How can I fix this?